# webpack failed to start react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am learning to use webpack to develop a react project, but I cannot start local services locally. It reports the following error.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import App from './App';
|
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
|
```

I suspect this is a babel compilation problem, but I have configured babel-loader, but it does not work. I Googled this issue for a long time, but I still didn't find the problem. Can you help me? Thanks!

And this is my configuration files.

```
// webpack.common.js
const path = require('path');
const commonConfig = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    '../src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }]
  }
};
module.exports = commonConfig;
```

```
// webpack.dev.js
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const path = require('path');

const devConfig =  merge(commonConfig, {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000
  }
})
module.exports = devConfig;
```

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.11.4",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
  "webpack": "^4.44.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
```

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Comment: I guess since your file ends in `.js`, it's not picked up by the babel loader. Since you're creating a React app, unless you want to acquire a deep understanding of how webpack/babel works, simply use create-react-app.

Comment: Have you configured Babel to apply the React preset?

Comment: But my configuration is `test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/`, I think it can also work on `.js` files。@ChrisG

Comment: I configured `{ "presets": ["env", "react"] }` in the `. babelrc` file. @jonrsharpe

Comment: You seem to be mixing Babel 6 and 7, can you simplify the example further?

Comment: If you specify preset with `env`, you're likely to use babel 6. Are you using babel 6 too?. Can you share the package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

I found out where the problem was. I didn’t specify the `webpack.dev.js` file for the `npm run start` command in the scripts of `package.json`, and it worked after making the following changes.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js",
  },
```